# Kendo for Angular 2+ Charts. Change cursor type

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I need to change the cursor when I hover the series item (on Bar chart, Stacked Bar chart and on the Line chart). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible . You have to set the chart series tooltip using

```
 <kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
    <ng-template let-value="value" let-category="category" let-dataItem="dataItem">
      Number of children: {{ dataItem.number }}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
```

Complete code is as  given  below

```
   <kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-tooltip>
    <ng-template kendoChartSeriesTooltipTemplate let-value="value">
      Default Content {{ value }}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-chart-tooltip>
  <kendo-chart-title text="Percentage of Children Not Vaccinated"></kendo-chart-title>
  <kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis-item
      [categories]="['1999', '', '2001', '', '2003','', '2005', '', '2007','', '2009', '', '2011', '', '2013','', '2015'  ]"
      [title]="{ text: 'Year' }">
    </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-category-axis>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="column" [data]="testData" field="percent" >
      <kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
        <ng-template let-value="value" let-category="category" let-dataItem="dataItem">
          Number of children: {{ dataItem.number }}
        </ng-template>
      </kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>

    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

To see the working version of the graph online. Please visit the website that I have built using angular

http://www.vaxinator.info/VaccinationInformation and click on the **Red Button** named 'Rise in anti vaccinations'. You would be able to see a nice kendo graph with an example

Comment: An example of what? Still a default cursor on hover.